# Can I change the phase which will trigger these plugins?

Tags: spring, docker, maven, testing, plugins

These plugins will create an openapi.yaml file based on my REST Controller:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileName>openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The file will be created when i run `mvn verify`.`mvn verify` will also run my tests which I dont need. When I run `mvn verify` in my dockerfile, it gives me this error:

*"Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."*

This happens because my database container is not created/running before `mvn verify`. If I run mvn package -DskipTests there is no problem.

Is there a way I can change the phase to package which will trigger the plugin and creates a yaml for me? I dont need the tests.

I tried with `<phase>package</phase>` but this would still run the tests which will cause me an error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin) the file can only be generated while the application is up and running. That's why you are already using Spring Boot maven plugin goals `start` and `stop`. This way your application is running when the `openapi` generate the yaml file. This is the correct setup. However it means that the `application.properties` file will be used and as consequence the *real* database will be connected.

I suggest to configure an embedded in-memory database instead of the target one. Spring Boot JPA will create it during the startup of application. To get it work without changing the original `application.properties` you can use a dedicated profile. Let's name it `inmemory`.

**Step 1**:

Add H2 dependency to the pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2**:

Create a file `application-inmemory.properties` in the `src/main/resources` folder with this content:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

**Step 3**:

Define active profile in `pom.xml` like this:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=inmemory</jvmArguments>
</configuration>
```

Now you can just run `mvn verify`. In the logs you will see that in the `pre-integration-test` phase the `jdbc:h2:mem:db` will be used.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! That is my first time working with in-memory database. So  now I have problem with the h2 database. I opened another question for this problem which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76449354/pre-integration-test-phase-does-not-use-my-h2-database-in-spring) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: I have edited my answer adding the steps to follow. I suggest to delete the other question as unnecessary duplicate.